# Highcharts hover delay and not rendering with multiple series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

As a disclaimer I am very new to JS.  That being said, I have multiple series that I am loading into Highcharts from a database. If loading single series the chart renders fine and is responsive.  Upon loading multiple series, the crosshairs for the data are delayed drastically upon hover and the chart doesn't even render on the screen in Chrome (Version 59.0.3071.104 (Official Build) (64-bit)) unless I zoom in quite a bit.  It will however render in Firefox and IE, but with slow response times. It will also save to disk fine on all browsers.

The charts are simple lines that consist of approx 33k data points per line.  I use some simple php function to loop through the data sets and generate the script.

```
<div id="container" style="width: 1200px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div> 

        <!-- 1. Add JQuery and Highcharts in the head of your page -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

        <!-- 2. You can add print and export feature by adding this line -->
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>


        <script>
            exporting:{
                            url:"http://localhost:8080/highcharts-export-web/"
                        };

                var chart = Highcharts.chart("container", {
                                chart: {
                                    zoomType: "x",
                                    panning: true,
                                    panKey: "shift",
                                    //~ plotShadow: true,
                                    plotBorderWidth: 1

                                },
                                tooltip: { enabled: false},
                                title: {
                                    text: "Experiments"
                                },


                                yAxis: {
                                    minorTickInterval: "auto",
                                    lineColor: "#000",
                                    lineWidth: 1,
                                    tickWidth: 1,
                                    tickColor: "#000",
                                    crosshair: {
                                        color: "blue",
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: "Y",


                                    }
                                },

                                xAxis: {
                                    //type: "datetime",
                                    minorTickInterval: "auto",
                                    lineColor: "#000",
                                    lineWidth: 1,
                                    tickWidth: 1,
                                    tickColor: "#000",
                                    crosshair: {
                                        color: "blue",
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: "X",
                                    },


                                },
                                legend: {
                                    layout: "vertical",
                                    align: "right",
                                    verticalAlign: "middle"
                                },

                                series : []


                            });






        $.getJSON('./from-sql.php?callback=data&zone=1055&ma=120', function(data) {


        chart.addSeries({
            data: data.data,

            });

    });


        $.getJSON('./from-sql.php?callback=data&zone=1056&ma=120', function(data) {


        chart.addSeries({
            data: data.data,

            });

    });


        $.getJSON('./from-sql.php?callback=data&zone=1&ma=120', function(data) {


        chart.addSeries({
            data: data.data,

            });

    });
    </script>
```

I wouldn't consider 33k points to be a huge number and from what I've read data grouping is enabled by default, which I thought would help. I was having rendering issues in the past and disabling the tooltip seemed to fix that problem. Am I doing something that is inherently wrong and making it slow?

Thanks in advance for any advice and/or tips.

Comment: A regular chart does not have grouping feature - for grouping you need Highstock library and StockChart (instead of Chart). Try to recreate the problem on jsfiddle or other sandbox - without a live example it is impossible to say what is wrong. You can also see the lazy loading example https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading - it makes more sense to fetch data on zoom than display so many points at once. You can also check the boost module https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/175-highcharts-performance-boost/

Comment: @morganfree,  using the boost module has dramatically improved the performance. All the series plot and are very responsive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

33k is big enough to downgrade the performance. Use special chart-group for that like [Master-detail chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail) or [Highstock series](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line)